# How to get a link to entity_reference in ListBuilder?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity (Person) with these fields: ID, nom, prenom, telephoneportable, estactive, adherentid, userID, created, changed.
I created it with baseFieldDefinitions.

adherentid is a 'entity_reference' link to another custom content entity 'Adherent'.
userID are is a 'entity_reference' link to standard Drupal 'User' entity.

In the PersonListBuilder, I try to have these ids showed as links to the corresponding entities.

Here is the code for userID (and it's working fine):

```
$row['userid']['data'] = array(
'#theme' => 'username',
'#account' => $entity->getUser(),
);
```

What should be the code for adherentid (can't make it work so far):

```
$row['adherentid']['data'] = array(
'#theme' => '???',
'#account' => $entity->getAdherent(),
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, that worked for me:

```
$adherent = $entity->getAdherent();  
$id = (int) $adherent->id->value;  
$row['adherentid']['data'] = array(  
  '#type' => 'link',  
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.association_adherent.canonical', array('association_adherent' => $id)),  
  '#title' => $adherent->designation->value,  
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the [Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x) render element, and by using the canonical link for the Adherent entity. This assumes that the Adherent entity type definition has a canonical link, and that the route is defined in your module's routing YAML.

```
$row['adherentid']['data'] = array(
 '#type' => 'link',
 '#url' => Uri::fromRoute('entity.adherent.canonical', ['association_adherent' => $id]),
 '#title' => 'My link',
);
```

Another possibility is to render the field, and use the display mode that provides a link to the entity using the entity label. However this is less accessible in the documentation to look up within a reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  
I updated my code accordingly:  

`$row['adherentid']['data'] = array(`
`'#theme' => 'link',`
`'#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.association_adherent.canonical'),`
`'#title' => 'My link',`
`);`

Unfortunately, I got 'Theme Hook link not found' in the log...  
And I don't know how to replace 'My link' by the correct adherent stuff (At least the ID)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed my answer. i forgot that link is now `#type` and not `#theme`. The link to the API page gives the correct info as well.

Comment: with `'#type' => 'link'`, I have now an error:
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: "Some mandatory parameters are missing ("association_adherent") to generate a URL for route "entity.association_adherent.canonical"."

Comment: With these modifications, it works!
Thanks for your help.
`$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.association_adherent.canonical', array('association_adherent' => $id));`
`$row['adherentid']['data'] = array(`
`'#type' => 'link',`
`'#url' => $url,`
`'#title' => $title,`
`);`